# How do I select the first instance of an element of a certain class enclosinga DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

Hi guys lets say I have the following html:

```
<div class="owner">
  <div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="">click</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="owner">
  <div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="">click</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to put code in the onclick handler so it results in selecting the element of class 'owner' which encloses it - so I don't have to refer to the parent element by typing in this.parentNode.parentNode etc

I'd appreciate if theres a way to do it using selectors from both prototype and jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$().parents(<selector>)` is your friend

```
$(a).click(function() {
   $(this).parents(".owner").css("background-color", "yellow");
})
```

[example](http://jsbin.com/ewidi3)

Comment: Cool - is there a similar function in prototype?

Comment: in prototype 'up' seems to be the equivalent to jquerys parents()
http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/up

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `this.parentNode.parentNode`?  If the structure is fixed, this will be faster and more efficient.

If the structure is not fixed, a jQuery way would be something like:

```
$(this).parentsUntil (".owner").filter (".owner");
```

Comment: This is a very simple example - at times the element is nested really deep inside and is alot of parentNodes away from the one I wish to target and most of the time I end up having to redesign the html a bit so I want to avoid having to redo all the javascript in such cases as its very dependant upon the actual positioning of the element itself.